# SwiftUI: Make image bigger on tap

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make an app and i want to make the image bigger when tapped. And when tapped outside the picture it would go back to normal. How is that possible? Found out there is  `.onTapGesture()` but can't seem to find how to make the image bigger with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926702/12299030?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `.scaleEffect` with a condition to scale up and down the view e.g

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                .resizable()
                .onTapGesture {
                    selected.toggle()
                }
                .scaleEffect(self.selected ? 1.5 : 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This was also what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: well, well... ;)